# Passing a class as argument to a method, then calling static methods

Tags: java, class, reflection, version, static-methods

I have a use case with a class existing in 2 versions of a package.

```java
package packageV1;

public class MyClass extends BaseClass{

 public static String example(){
      return "Version1";
    }
}
```

```java
package packageV2;

public class MyClass extends BaseClass{

 public static String example(){
     return "Version2";
      }
}
```

So far so good (I believe).

Then I have an application using that class, and to avoid rewriting the application for the different package version, I want to pass the class that should be use (ie for the package of interest) as argument to the application.
So something like

```java
public class Application{
      
      private Class<BaseClass> selectedClass;

      public void Application(Class<BaseClass> selectedClass){
               this.selectedClass = selectedClass;
               this.selectedClass.example();  // not possible
               }

}
```

I believe I could call `this.selectedClass.example();` if I were passing an instance of `MyClass` in the constructor, but then I would call static methods through a instance object, not nice right ?

On the other hand, in the example above `selectedClass` is a Class object, so I can't call the static method `example` as above.

Does this mean I should use reflection ? like `selectedClass.getMethod(name, parameterTypes)`.
Looks overly complicated to me.

Or is there a better design ?

Comment: "Does this mean I should use reflection?" Yes it does. If you want to work with Class objects, there is no other way.

Comment: Can you use functional programming? Could just ask for a Supplier<String>?

Comment: The entire architecture of your application is pretty unclear, so it is impossible to give you 'the right answer'. Based on what you have given, I believe you have probably come up with a less than great solution for your problem. Based on what I've seen, I advice you to take a look at the Command Pattern. If this does not help you further, please provide us with more information. Maybe a link to a 'bare minimum' of your project, or the project itself.

Comment: Just use a good old switch: `switch (name)  { case "packageV1.MyClass" -> packageV1.MyClass.example(); case "packageV2.MyClass" -> packageV2.MyClass.exampe(); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@javadev is right. Using reflection is almost always a really bad idea. It is that which over complicates.

There is no need for reflection here. The ability to invoke static methods on instances was rapidly realised to be a design error. So much so that there is a subsequent highly unorthogonal design choice in that it does not work for static methods that are members of interfaces.

The simple solution is to move the static methods to instance methods of stateless objects. No `Class`, or other reflection, necessary. This is an application of the Strategy design pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Using a static method this way is not a good design, and not according to the Object Orinted principles.

My tip is to try changing "example()" to be a regular method, and not static.