# How to create constructor in java parameterized with class?

Tags: java, class, constructor, parameter-passing, static-methods

I want to have a class to run other classes in java, like constructor parameterized with a class to run that class later on, similar to this

```
class MyClass{
    Class classToRun;
    public MyClass(Class c) {
        super();
        this.classToRun = c;
    }
    public void runClass(){
        classToRun.someStaticMethod();
    }
}
```

where ***classToRun*** possible classes doesn't have a common ancestor, but all have method ***someStaticMethod***, and have no idea about MyClass, which runs them.

But there are problems, like inner classes cannot have static methods, classes cannot be cast Class, etc.

There are solutions for parameterized with class methods, like

[How do I pass a class as a parameter in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872978/how-do-i-pass-a-class-as-a-parameter-in-java)

[Passing a class as an argument to a method in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14846853/passing-a-class-as-an-argument-to-a-method-in-java)

but not for constructors.

What is the proper solution to do this?

Comment: You cannot call `classToRun.someStaticMethod();` anyways if `classToRun` is a `Class`. You need reflection code to call that function.

Comment: Also, please read: [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Comment: @Turing85
You are free to put down a better working solution instead of a non working frame of idea, if you can.

Comment: WebComer without putting some type of limitation on the classes, how would you assume you can guarantee that method is there?

Comment: @WebComer The current design is broken. There is no proper (i.e. clean) solution to the problem since - 1. there is no common superclass of those classes and - 2. even if there were, static methods are not inherited. I recommend to reevaluate the overall design.

Comment: @ Stultuske
 If a class don't have someStaticMethod, exception at run time may be thrown, that is just ok.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing a class as argument to a method, then calling static methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65791611/passing-a-class-as-argument-to-a-method-then-calling-static-methods)

Comment: @Turing85
I really want a better solution instead broken one. The idea is to parameterize class with another with  someStaticMethod.

Comment: @Joe
The class to run doesn't inherit BaseClass, it just contains static method someStaticMethod. That's all. Beside of this, the answer you have mentioned is not a complete working solution for the problem. If you believe, it is a solution, you may put a full working proof code. So far, only Joop Eggen's solution fits the requirements.

Comment: @Turing85
 For the task, no common superclass of those classes to run is one of the main requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Use lambdas and pass the method reference: they match on the method signature. For `void someStaticMethod()` you can use `Runnable`.

```
class MyClass{
    private final Runnable methodToRun;
    public MyClass(Runnable someStaticMethod) {
        methodToRun = someStaticMethod;
    }
    public void runClass(){
        methodToRun.run();
    }
}

new MyClass(SomeClass::someStaticMethod).runClass();
```

You cannot enforce that the method passed has the right name, but looks even neater IMHO.

Comment: The classToRun shouldn't be limited to Runnable interface.

Comment: To call the methods you must have a method signature, for `String someStaticMethod (double)` use `DoubleFunction<String>` and `return methodToRun.apply(3.14);`

Comment: The class itself does not need to implement the interface, it is structurally matched (method signature).

Comment: @
Joop Eggen
Yes, thanks, very neat solution, btw! 
But I would name methodToRun like runnableForMethodToRun, as it is a Runnable instance.
It's a bit weird for me, a static method turned to be a Runnable, and Java did swallow that! ))) Yeah, I know, may be reflection works, but looks like a kind of a hack for me)))

Comment: It is the java way to have function and method "pointers." So it fits your requirements. And I agree: good naming is important.

Comment: It fits the requirements, and it's coool!)))

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand what [generics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7815528/14922125) are.

interface

```java
public interface SomeInterface {
    void someStaticMethod();
}
```

use

```java
class MyClass<T extends SomeInterface>{
    T classToRun;
    public MyClass(T c) {
        super();
        this.classToRun = c;
    }
    public void runClass(){
        classToRun.someStaticMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is the classToRun classes do not extend a common SomeInterface, just have someStaticMethod to be run.

Comment: @WebComer Then you have to use reflection or annotation.

Comment: Reflection looks like a better idea, may be you can fix your solution.
Just guess about your words about annotation, but you may put down your annotation solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

As 2 of 3 answers were not to the point, I decided to publish fixed versions of both answers as far as they can be fixed.

The ***f1sh*** version from the above should like follows:

```java
public class ClassToRunOthers {
    Class classToRun;
    public ClassToRunOthers(Class c) {
        this.classToRun = c;
    }
    public void runClass() throws Exception {
        Optional<Method> method = Arrays.stream(classToRun.getDeclaredMethods()).filter(m -> m.getName().equals("someStaticMethod")).findFirst();
        if(!method.isPresent()) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
        method.get().invoke(null);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ClassToRunOthers mc = new ClassToRunOthers(SomeClass.class);
        mc.runClass();
    }
}

class SomeClass {
    static void someStaticMethod() {
        System.out.println("test");
    }
}
```

The ***zwei*** solution above can not be fixed without reflection, as generics is not to the point. Evan if you try to parametrize not with `SomeInerface` (because `SomeClass` does not extend a common `SomeInterface`), but with Object, it is still won't solve the problem:

```java
public class MyClass<T extends Object> {
    T classToRun;

    public MyClass(T c) {
        super();
        this.classToRun = c;
    }

    public void runClass() {
        //        classToRun.someStaticMethod(); // Cannot resolve method 'someStaticMethod' in 'T'
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass mc = new MyClass(SomeClass.class);
    }
}

class SomeClass {
    static void someStaticMethod() {
        System.out.println("test");
    }
}
```

This can be fixed like the above, via reflection.
I believe, it can be done with annotations in some elegant way, and may be someone will share us with such a solution or I will do it by myself as time permits.
By now for myself, a solution with saving class name in the String in constructor next day after the question been asked did the trick.

Answer (score -1):

You will have to use reflection if you want to execute a method when you only have the `Class` instance.

In the code below, `runClass` finds the method of the class using it's name as a `String`, then executes it. This code assumes that the method is static, also ignoring any Exception handling.

The following code prints `"test"`:

```
class MyClass {
    Class classToRun;
    public MyClass(Class c) {
        this.classToRun = c;
    }
    public void runClass() throws Exception {
        Optional<Method> method = Arrays.stream(classToRun.getDeclaredMethods()).filter(m -> m.getName().equals("someStaticMethod")).findFirst();
        if(!method.isPresent()) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
        method.get().invoke(null);
    }
}


class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MyClass mc = new MyClass(Main.class);
        mc.runClass();
    }

    static void someStaticMethod() {
        System.out.println("test");
    }
}
```

Comment: The code is working, but MyClass shouldn't be static inner one, it's in another package.

Comment: that doesnt make a difference. My code is just an example, the code in `runClass` works with any class as long as the static method is not private.

Comment: @WebComer edited the code to make that change clear

Comment: SomeClassToRun (you named it Main) with someStaticMethod shouldn't contain MyClass. It's not even know about it.

Comment: You just didn't bother to read nor question requirements, nor your code in your solution.
The requirement is SomeClass, which you named Main, should have no idea about MyClass, that run it.
But the code you provided have even instance of MyClass in Main code, which is inappropriate, so it is not a solution for the problem stated.

Comment: And don't delete my comment again. It clearly states the problem with your solution.